# What are the difference between `\b` vs `\S` in PCRE grep?

Tags: bash, pcregrep

I know now that `\b` is for `Word Boundaries`

while

`\s` and `\S` is for `Shorthand Character Classes`

where

`\s` (lowercase) is for whitespace (space, tab, vtab, newline)

and

`\S` (uppercase) is the other way around. Anything but whitespace

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat space.txt 
0space
1 spaces
2  spaces
3   spaces
4    spaces
wolf@linux:~$
```

I don't see any difference in these 2 commands.

```
wolf@linux:~$ grep -P '\S\s\S' space.txt 
1 spaces
wolf@linux:~$ grep -P '\S\s\S\S' space.txt 
1 spaces
wolf@linux:~$
```

vs

```
wolf@linux:~$ grep -P '\b\s\b' space.txt
1 spaces
wolf@linux:~$ grep -P '\b\s\b\b' space.txt
1 spaces
wolf@linux:~$
```

Reference: https://staff.washington.edu/weller/grep.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An illustration using GNU `sed`:

Put parentheses around each match of `\b` in the string `Hello world!`:

```
$ sed 's/\b/(&)/g' <<<'Hello world!'
()Hello() ()world()!
```

As you can see, the `\b` does not match any characters.  Instead it matches the zero width word boundaries at the start and end of each word.

Then we do the same thing with `\S`:

```
$ sed 's/\S/(&)/g' <<<'Hello world!'
(H)(e)(l)(l)(o) (w)(o)(r)(l)(d)(!)
```

The `\S` matches every non-space character.

When you want to match a certain number of spaces, you could do that with `\S\s{3}\S`.  This would match three spaces, but would also require that those spaces are surrounded on either side by non-space characters.  The matching of that expression would fail if the spaces occurred at the start or end of a line.

If you use `\b\s{3}\b`, you require that the three spaces are surrounded by word-boundaries.  This *would* match even though the spaces may occur at the start or end of the line.  However, it would fail if the spaces are surrounded by other non-word characters, as in the string `hello;   ;world`.

As a side note: Be aware that `\s` matches both spaces and tab characters (and a few others), just like the POSIX character class `[[:space:]]` does . If you want to match only spaces, use a space character.  A non-space can be matched with `[^ ]`.